# SQL - Count All Cells In The Entire Table That Are Not NULL And Not Empty

Tags: sql, count, cell

I have recently been asked to do a count of all the cells in some tables that are not NULL and not empty/blank.

The issue is, I have about 80 tables and some of those tables have dozens of columns and others have hundreds of columns.

Is there a query I could use to count all cells from all columns that fit a specific criteria (in this case not NULL and not empty/blank)?

I have done some searching and it seems most answers revolve around single columns or tables that only have like 3-5 columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting SQL with pandas using pymysql or pyodbc connector and then iterate over each column using for loop and apply the count function on it.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

con = pymysql.connect('[host name]', '[user name]','[your password]', '[database name]')

cursor = con.cursor()


df = pd.read_sql('select * from [table name]',con) # SQL converted to pandas dataframe
print(df)


for col in df.columns: # loops through column
    count_ = df[col].count()
    print(count_) # returns count for non-nan values
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is on a client server that we do not have permission to install software on.

Comment: @Mark sorry to hear that but I believe there should be no restrictions when it comes to data analysis